# PyQt5 QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO and lag in GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Prints out this and the whole GUI keeps lagging.

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
```

I have created an application on my previous computer but now when I cloned the git repository of that project onto this new laptop the given warning is printed out and the GUI seems to exceed the limits of my laptop's screen and when I click or hover on something it does not do anything except after a while and the program seems to glitch a lot.

**EDIT**

LAG was fixed, I had a web scraper in my application and the data was exported as a datatype named lxml and the exception was handled by my own error handler which didn't support that type of errors so it wasn't showing up.

Comment: That is a warning that only indicates that a different environment variable should be used that should not cause you any problems. What version of python, PyQt5, OS are you using in your new machine and in the previous one?

Comment: I am not quite sure, my previous machine is not around atm I will get to it tomorrow though but the new machine got a **Python==3.6** All the other dependencies are the latest versions. and yes they are the exact same OS